# How do I create a list as a key of a dictionary and add to the in different parts list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a for loop that runs through a CSV file and grabs certain elements and creates a dictionary based on two variables.

Code:

```
for ind, row in sf1.iterrows():
    sf1_date = row['datekey']
    sf1_ticker = row['ticker']
    company_date[sf1_ticker] = [sf1_date]
```

I for example during the first iteration of the for loop, `sf1_ticker = 'AAPL'` and `sf1_date = '2020/03/01'` and the next time around, `sf1_ticker = 'AAPL'` and `sf1_date = '2020/06/01'`, how do I make the key of 'AAPL' in the dictionary equal to `['2020/03/01', '2020/06/01']`

Comment: You can't. Keys for dictionaries need to be hashable types, and Python's `list` is not a hashable type. Use a `tuple` instead.

Comment: What code would I use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that when you say "key" you actually mean "value". The keys for a dictionary are the things that you use to lookup values in the dictionary. In your case ticker is the key and a list of dates are the values, e.g. you want a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'AAPL': ['2020/03/01', '2020/06/01'].
 'MSFT': ['2020/04/01', '2020/09/01']}
```

Here the strings AAPL and MSFT are dictionary keys. The date lists are the values associated with each key.

Your code can not construct such a dictionary because it is assigning a new value to the key. The following code will either create a new key in the dictionary `company_date` if the key does not already exist in the dictionary, or *replace* the existing value if the key already exists:

```
company_date[sf1_ticker] = [sf1_date]
```

You need to append to a list of values in the dict, rather than replace the current list, if any. There are a couple of ways to do it; [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) is one:

```
company_date = {}
for ind, row in sf1.iterrows():
    sf1_date = row['datekey']
    sf1_ticker = row['ticker']
    company_date.setdefault(sf1_ticker, []).append(sf1_date)
```

Another way is with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

company_date = defaultdict(list)
for ind, row in sf1.iterrows():
    sf1_date = row['datekey']
    sf1_ticker = row['ticker']
    company_date[sf1_ticker].append(sf1_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new dictionary and add the date to the list if it exists. Otherwise, create the entry.

```
ticker_dates = {}

# Would give ticker_dates = {"AAPL":['2020/03/01', '2020/06/01']}
for ind,row in sft1.iterrows():
    sf1_ticker = row['ticker']
    sf1_date = row['datekey']
    if sf1_ticker in ticker_dates:
       ticker_date[sf1_ticker].append(sf1_date)
    else:
       ticker_dates[sf1_ticker] = [sf1_date]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a defaultdict, which can be setup to add an empty list to any item that doesn't exist.  It generally acts like a dictionary otherwise.

```python
from collections import defaultdict

rows = [
    ['AAPL', '2020/03/01'], 
    ['AAPL', '2020/06/01'],
    ['GOOGL', '2021/01/01']
]

company_date = defaultdict(list)
for ticker, date in rows:
    company_date[ticker].append(date)

print(company_date)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'AAPL': ['2020/03/01', '2020/06/01'], 'GOOGL': ['2021/01/01']})
```